# How to write ~/.haskeline so that ghci or haskeline can behave properly on `home` and `end`

Tags: haskell, keyboard, read-eval-print-loop, ghci, haskeline

My question is how to make my `ghci` react properly on my `home` and `end` press.

I learned that `ghci` use `haskeline` to react to user input, and `haskeline`'s behavior is partially defined in `~/.haskeline` to some extent.

I have being suffering from the lack of support for `end` key and `home` key of `ghci` for a long time. So I tried to define my own `~/.haskeline` file.

Firstly:

```
bind: a home
bind: b end

keyseq: "a" home
keyseq: "b" end

bind: left home
bind: right end
```

Both behave as when I press `a` then the cursor to the most left and similarly to others.

Secondly:

```
bind: home a
bind: end b
```

It shows that my `ghci` seems to ignore my `home` and `end` press absolutely.

So how could I send `home` and `end` key to `ghci` and `haskline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* work by default. Most likely Haskeline isn't recognizing whatever your keyboard sends as the `home` and `end` keys. This depends on your OS and terminal setup.

You might want to adjust your `$TERM` setting to something that supports those keys, after which `Haskeline` *should* pick them up automatically.

Otherwise, the [Haskeline trac wiki](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/CustomKeyBindings#Control-leftright) has a recipe for getting it to recognize unknown key sequences, which should work on POSIX systems (not on Windows, where `home` and `end` should also already be working by default). Adapting this to the current case:

```
$ ghc -e getLine
<press home, then return>...some noise here...
"...haskell string for home..."
$ ghc -e getLine
<press end, then return>...some other noise...
"...haskell string for end..."
```

Add the corresponding lines to `~/.haskeline`:

```
keyseq: your-terminal "...haskell string for home..." home
keyseq: your-terminal "...haskell string for end..." end
```

where `your-terminal` is whatever's in your `$TERM` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't know much about `Most likely Haskeline isn't recognizing whatever your keyboard sends as the home and end keys. This depends on your OS and terminal setup.` I learned that for the first time today.

But I successfully wrote a `~/.haskeline` adapted to my laptop(Ubuntu 14.04, ghc-7.10.2).

```
keyseq: "\ESCOH" home
keyseq: "\ESCOF" end
```